# Drupal - How to customize theme_user_list

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, themes

I have a list of users, where I use theme_user_list in order to display them. The problem is that I don't want this long list with users, instead I would like to put them in three columns. I tried with theme_table but it doesn't support objects at all.

Please help me here.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this function to `template.php` file of your theme:

```
 function phptemplate_user_list($users, $title = NULL) {
      if (!empty($users)) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
          $items[] = theme('username', $user);
        }
      }
      $output = "";
      $output .= "<table><tr>";
      for($i = 0; count($items) > $i; $i++){
        $output .= "<td>" . $items[$i]. "</td>";
        if($i%3 == 0 && $i != 0){
          $output .= "</tr><tr>";
        }
    }
      $output .= "</tr></table>";
      return $output;
    }
```

You will resive table with 3 columns

Comment: can we have any alternate of it? Because I want to do it in module